# System crashes at logout

Tags: 16.04, radeon, crash, logout

I'm experiencing an issue with a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. Every time I try to log out the system crashes and I get this:

[image: Oops]

I tried switching users; it does the same thing after a few seconds. Also, this happens if I log out of the guest session as well.

It might be worth mentioning that I didn't install much on it, and anything I can think of related to this is Unity Tweaker - which I already reset to default settings but with no luck.

My specs are:
Laptop Lenovo 15.6" Ideapad 500-15ISK
Intel® Core™ i7-6500U (4M Cache, up to 3.10 GHz)
8GB RAM
128GB SSD
Radeon R7 M360 4GB

Could this be related to the fact that also Ubuntu does not recognize my Radeon R7 360 card? I mean if I run `lscpi` i get only Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics, although there is a dedicated Radeon card installed.

Also, after resetting all Unity settings to default, I rebooted the machine and had to reset the configuration for Unity and reload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering it is complaining about "amdgpu" it's pretty safe to say it is a problem involving the dGPU. Does it detect the GPU if you manage your drivers in **Software & Updates**, found in **System Settings**?

Personally I disabled my dGPU in the BIOS on my laptop, since it only gave me troubles both in Windows and in Linux and I rarely use my laptop for anything else than basic office use and virtual labs anyways.

*Cheers*

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Bram. No, it doesn't detect it. In the Aditional drivers it shows up Unknown: Unknown - Using Processor microcode firmware for intel CPUs frrom intel microcode (propietary). I am also worried that this seems to be the only aditional driver that it detects.

Comment: Sadly, Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have any proprietary AMD drivers anymore. If it isn't supported by the open-source drivers, I don't think there's much hope for this particular GPU in the near future. If you don't care much about the extra performance the GPU gives you, I'd try disabling it in the BIOS. Otherwise, I'm sorry.

Comment: Actually, I found something related to this: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Beta-Driver-for-Vulkan-Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: I would only try it if you have either a backup or just don't mind if you have to reinstall. I've got a bad experience with installing GPU drivers manually, often resulting in either an unstable system, or it not booting into the desktop at all.

Comment: I have to agree with @Bram Koert. I had problems with AMD GPU in Lenovo laptop already with Ubuntu 14.04. I am not installing 16.04 just because I have AMD. I will wait for few months more so that the major errors are corrected.

Comment: Yea, well I already installed so I'm just going to wait a few months until I can use my amd chipset. Until then, many thanks @Bram for your suggestions, I changed switchable graphics to UMA in BIOS and now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug in Ubuntu Launchpad:
[Ubuntu 16 Kernel BUG (“Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP”) related to amdgpu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767163/ubuntu-16-kernel-bug-oops-0000-1-smp-related-to-amdgpu/767490#767490)

The workaround to fix the issue is installing the latest kernel package from mainline repository.

Comment: You can also fix this issue upgrading your system to 16.04.2 with Hardware Enablement (kernel 4.8).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by blacklisting the kernel module 'amdgpu'.
Open `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add the following line to the end of the file:

```
blacklist amdgpu
```

In order for this to take effect, you must update your `initrd` image by running:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

After a reboot, you should no longer experience crashing upon logout.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the Intel "turbo boost" in the BIOS which "increases performance" of the CPU and GPU. This took care of the logout issue.